# Find shortest path in graph by following orders to visit node

Tags: graph-theory, shortest-path, dijkstra, a-star

The source is A. The order of the nodes is ["C", "D", "E"], which must be processed to reach the goal.

I found the solution using Dijkstra's algorithm by finding the shortest path from A-C, C-D, D-E. Is there an optimised way to find the shortest path in one move. Can we do better with A*? If A* increases the performance, how can we define a heuristic function?

Here is my graph.

Shortest Path: A - B - C - D - C - E . Here we can revisit node again if it contributes to shortest path.

[image]

Comment: The other option is the [Floyd Warshall algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd–Warshall_algorithm). It finds the shortest path between all pairs of vertices in O(V^3) time. But that's only going to beat Dijkstra's algorithm if 1) the number of edges is much larger than the number of vertices, and 2) the number of vertices being visited is a large percentage of the total number of vertices. Both of those conditions are true in the example, but I don't know what the typical graph will be.

Answer (score 1):

Dijkstra's Algorithm is the best option for finding the shortest path in a graph. Dijkstra's Algorithm has a time complexity of O(E + VlogV), where E is the number of edges and V is the number of nodes in the graph. The A* Algorithm has a slower time complexity.

Answer (score 0):

> Can we do better with A*?

No.

Dijkstra ( note spelling ) is the best way to find the shortest path between two nodes in a graph.

A* is used when the entire graph is unavailable, just the local surroundings.  It is always slower than Dijkstra when Dijkstra is feasible.